# Construct binary search tree from N unsorted integers

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, binary-search-tree

If I have `N` unsorted integers in my program and I want to make a binary search tree from these integers, is there any efficient algorithm to do that? can we do that in `O(n)` time complexity? the approach I know is very time-consuming.

Comment: It is not possible to do this in `O(n)` if there aren't limits on the integers. The proof is that if such an algorithm exists, we would be able to sort an array by constructing and iterating over the tree, which takes `O(n)`. It's been proven that comparison sorting can't be done faster than `O(n log n)`, so such an algorithm must not exist.

Comment: What is the approach you know and what means "very time-consuming"?

Comment: Either you're doing it in `O(n lg n)`, which is the best you'll get, or you're doing something terribly wrong. Either way, without seeing your code this is just useless speculation

Comment: @FeiXiang what if we want to make Binary Maxheap from those unsorted N integers? if yes, then how?

Comment: It can be done in `O(n)`, the same way it's done in [heapsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort).